# Restarting task if it fails

Tags: c#, task, continuations

I'm trying to restart one of multiple tasks if it fails. Im using `.ContinueWith(t => { HandleException(t); }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);` where the `HandleException(t)` method should find the task in the array of excisting tasks and create a new one in its place. Only the task passed to my `HandleException(t)` method is different from original task so I'm not able to find it in my excisting tasks. Also the excisting task is still running at the time the exception is handled.

Example:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;

static Task[] tasks;
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    tasks = new Task[2];
    for (int i = 0; i < tasks.Count(); i++)
    {
        tasks[i] = Task.Run(() => { Thread.Sleep(1000); throw new Exception("BOOM"); })
             .ContinueWith(t => { HandleException(t); }
             , TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);

        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Task {0} started", tasks[i].Id));
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}

static void HandleException(Task task)
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Task {0} stopped", task.Id));

    // Check task status
    for (int i = 0; i < tasks.Count(); i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Task {0} status = {1}", i, tasks[i].Status));
    }
    // fFind and restart the task here
    if (tasks.Contains(task))
    {
        int index = Array.IndexOf(tasks, task);
        tasks[index] = Task.Run(() => { Thread.Sleep(1000); throw new Exception("BOOM"); })
         .ContinueWith(t => { HandleException(t); }
         , TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);

        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Task {0} started", tasks[index].Id));
    }
}
```

My application results in:

```
Task 3 started
Task 6 started
Task 5 stopped
Task 0 status = Running
Task 2 stopped
Task 1 status = Running
Task 0 status = Running
Task 1 status = Running
```

Since the task passed to the `HandleException(t)` is different from the original task, it is not found in the `tasks[]` and thus not restarted. Also looking at the states of the `tasks[]` it is not yet stopped. How can I properly restart my task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you store continuation task in your array, not original task (that is - you store result of `ContinueWith`). To fix, store original task instead:

```
var task = Task.Run(() => { Thread.Sleep(1000); throw new Exception("BOOM");});
task.ContinueWith(t => { HandleException(t); }
         , TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
tasks[i] = task;
```

Comment: Awesome, this was indeed the issue. It also fixed the task status.

Comment: @Evk Since HandleException(t) is a recursive call, doesn't it introduce stack overflow eventually?

Comment: @MaximPodkolzin no, because all happens on different threads. New task is started via `Task.Run`, this grabs a thread from thread pool > exception is thrown > HandleException is called, potentially again on different thread > `Task.Run` is called again and another thread is grabbed from thread pool (the same cannot be used because it's busy executing HandleException) > current thread finishes execution and returns back to pool. For stack overflow the same thread should execute function recursively, but here we have different threads (and so different stacks).